# How to unpack dictionary of dictionaries into structured DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe that consists of supplier information.  Within this is a columns called 'attributes'.  This field contains a dictionary of dictionaries, each potentially containing different key: pair data.  I want to unpack these attributes into the DataFrame as Column Headers.

DF = `attributes  companyName id
4   [{'attributeName': 'File Discount', 'attribute...   Ace 130
13  [{'attributeName': 'Payment Terms', 'attribute...   B66ks   240`

An example attributes cell:

```
 [{'attributeName': 'File Discount',
  'attributeType': 'int',
  'attributeValue': '15'},
 {'attributeName': 'Returns',
  'attributeType': 'text',
  'attributeValue': 'Full SOR on all'}]
```

I want it to create a DF column header from 'attributeName' and the value as 'attributeValue'.
So in this example, it would return headers of 'File Discount' & 'Returns' and values of '15' and 'Full SOR on all'.

How do I best tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new dictionary for each row with extract `attributeName` and `attributeValue` values and add all original columns with [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
a = [{'attributeName': 'File Discount',
  'attributeType': 'int',
  'attributeValue': '15'},
 {'attributeName': 'Returns',
  'attributeType': 'text',
  'attributeValue': 'Full SOR on all'}]

b = [{'attributeName': 'File',
     'attributeType': 'int',
     'attributeValue': '48'}]

df = pd.DataFrame({'companyName':['Ace','B66ks'],
                   'attributes':[a,b],
                   'id':[130,240]})
print (df)
  companyName                                         attributes   id
0         Ace  [{'attributeName': 'File Discount', 'attribute...  130
1       B66ks  [{'attributeName': 'File', 'attributeType': 'i...  240

L = [{y.get('attributeName'):y.get('attributeValue') for y in v} 
      for k, v in df.pop('attributes').items()]
print (L)
[{'File Discount': '15', 'Returns': 'Full SOR on all'}, {'File': '48'}]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(L, index=df.index).join(df)
print (df1)
  File File Discount          Returns companyName   id
0  NaN            15  Full SOR on all         Ace  130
1   48           NaN              NaN       B66ks  240
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  You've helped me a few times on here - much appreciated!  This is working well for me but I have one tweak that I can't figure out... I want the DF headers to be the 'attributeName' data (ie 'File Discount', 'Returns', 'Payment Terms' with the field populated by 'attributeValue'.value (ie 15, 'Full SOR...', '30 days...'.  Can I achieve this using this method?

Comment: Perfect solution.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

there's a pandas function that can be used on the dataframe unstack() and stack()
here's the link to the documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html